# performance between varchar(1) vs char(1)

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

Is there any performance difference between `varchar(1)` and `char(1)`? Which RDBMS handle these two datatypes and sizes in different ways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference will be negligible in most cases.  Concentrate your performance oriented design efforts in places where it will make a real difference, like table composition and index design.

It helps to divide the design effort into two layers: logical design and physical design.
Most of the performance oriented effort is in the second stage, physical design.

In logical design, flexibility trumps performance.  Except when it doesn't.

Comment: Flexibility should almost never trump performance! I guarantee the user wants performacne over flexibility even when they say they want flexibility.

Comment: Perhaps not: http://www.nikoport.com/2012/09/05/char1-2-vs-varchar1-2-to-be-null-or-to-be-not-null/

Answer (score 15):

In MS SQL `VARCHAR(1)` uses **three** bytes of storage and `CHAR(1)` uses **one** byte of storage.

`CHAR(1)` is more efficient than `VARCHAR(1)` in processing and storage.

The *breakeven* point on `VARCHAR` would be anything greater than 3 characters if using variable length data.

If using fixed length then `CHAR` is always more efficient by two bytes.

REF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle

> The VARCHAR2(1) and CHAR(1) are identical in all aspects. There is no
>   compelling reason to use the CHAR type in that case, and to avoid any
>   confusion, I “just say no,” even for the CHAR(1) field.

Reference: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476

Comment: Is not true for drivers. Oracle .NET drivers differ both.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Oracle is concerned....

CHAR(2) will always use two bytes/characters of storage. VARCHAR2(2) may only use one. So the general case is to use VARCHAR2 instead of CHAR.

In practice you shouldn't see a difference performance wise for a one character column.

Since there's never a never a benefit from CHAR, I always use VARCHAR2.

Comment: The varchar will still have to store at least a byte for the length of the string, though, so you can never have less than 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

it hardly matters, since you are using 1 byte in both cases.

but long story short, varchar is variable size & char is fixed size. in large quantities this can make a difference in storage space as well as affect computation time.

performance wise, use char if data is going to be fixed length. if you are flexible with varying length of your data then use varchar.

Comment: *** NOT 1 byte in both cases ! *** - 

for example - MYSQL v5.0 docs say varchar storage requirements for varchar(M) requires 'L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes' (where L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value).

So you'd be using 1 byte for the CHAR(1), and 2 bytes for VARCHAR(1). In which case you're using 100% MORE storage space for this column.

This may or may not be a big deal depending on the usage situation. Worth pointing out the difference though in case it is pertinent.

(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding after reading MySQL's description of VARCHAR and CHAR is that if you're data is always going to be the same length, then CHAR could potentially save you a single byte of data because VARCHAR requires the storage of a byte separate from the actual data in order to record how long the data is. However, if you're data isn't a constant length and you're thinking of space considerations, it would make sense to use VARCHAR because CHAR will always use a byte for every bit of the declared length whether there is anything in that space.

In the end, though, it probably doesn't make that big of a difference as the amount of data involved is quite small.

Here's where I got my information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html If you follow the link, pay special attention to the little chart as it gives examples of how the data would be handled with VARCHAR vs. CHAR.